# Windows 8.1 app - AppBarButton press button style

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

When you press an appbar button - this is the style:

[image]

But then it changes back to the default style. 
To let the user know that they pressed the button I'd like the style to be the same as the pressed style.

When the button is clicked i do a switch in the style for the button.

```
  if (button.ClickMode == ClickMode.Release)
  {
      button.Style = Application.Current.Resources["PressedAppBarButtonStyle"] as Style;
  }
```

I tried to keep this simple and did:

```
<Style x:Key="PressedAppBarButtonStyle" TargetType="AppBarButton">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />        
</Style>
```

This is the resulting image:

[image]

Problem.  The background color is not the white background that I thought i'd get.  I even put in the names of the colors like red, blue, purple, etc. but it didn't change the background color.

Any suggestions on how to get the background color to be white like the pressed button style?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the complete theme.
I copied an existing button theme and made the changes there to the colors.

This is where I needed to change the colors.

I wonder if there is an easier way to set the background color. Hmm...oh well. At least it works now.